# Getting NoSuchElementException when running this method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

My method runs, but then gets an exception after executing once.  I don't understand why.  Line 24, the line noted in the exception, is at "choice=in.nextInt();"

Here is my exception:

> 1 Find an item.
>   2 Display all items.
>   3 Update item.
>   4 Save item to disk.
>   5 Quit.
>   1
>   You chose to find an item from file.
>   Enter the sku of the dvd you wish to find.
>   857295
>   857295     Star.Wars              152
>  
>   1 Find an item.
>   2 Display all items.
>   3 Update item.
>   4 Save item to disk.
>   5 Quit.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>       at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>     at version4.version4.main(version4.java:24)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class version4 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean exit = false;
int choice = 0;

while (!exit)
{
    System.out.println("1 Find an item.\n2 Display all items.\n3 Update item.\n4 Save item to disk.\n5 Quit.");
    choice = in.nextInt();
    switch (choice){

    case 1: System.out.println("You chose to find an item from file."); findItem(); break;
    case 2: System.out.println("You chose to display all items."); readDisplay(); break;
    case 3: System.out.println("You chose to update an item."); itemUpdate(); break;
    case 4: System.out.println("You chose to save an item to disk."); itemAdd(); break;
    case 5: exit = true; in.close(); break;
    default: System.out.println("That is not a valid option."); break;
}
} 
System.out.println("Goodbye.");
} 

public static void findItem() throws FileNotFoundException {

    FileReader reader = new FileReader("read_record.txt");
    Scanner fin = new Scanner(reader);
    String str = null;
    ArrayList<String> dvdfile = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (fin != null && fin.hasNext()) { // do we have a scanner, is there anything to read?
      while (fin.hasNext()) { // while there's something to read...
        str = fin.next(); // read it.
        if (str == null) { // end if it's null
          break;
        }
        dvdfile.add(str); // otherwise add it.
      }
    } fin.close();

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the sku of the dvd you wish to find.");
    String dvdSku = kb.next();

    int index = dvdfile.indexOf(dvdSku);

    // Finds the dvd that matches sku entered, and prints out its attributes under correct rows.
    String skuToFind = dvdfile.get(index); String titleToFind = dvdfile.get(index+1); String lengthToFind = dvdfile.get(index+2);
    System.out.printf("%-10s %-15s %10s %n",skuToFind,titleToFind,lengthToFind);
    kb.close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are calling next even if the scanner no longer has a next element to provide... throwing the exception. you need to check `Scanner#hasNext()` before you invoke `Scanner#next()`

The code would be

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean exit = false;
    int choice = 0;

    while (!exit)
    {
        System.out.println("1 Find an item.\n2 Display all items.\n3 Update item.\n4 Save item to disk.\n5 Quit.");
        while(in.hasNext()){
        //next token available
        if(in.hasNextInt()){
        /next token is an int value
        choice = in.nextInt();
        }
}
}
```

As per the documentation

```
public boolean hasNext()
```

Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. **This method may block while waiting for input to scan**. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Comment: Still getting the same exception with that.  It says line 24, which would be at "choice=in.nextInt()"

Comment: Old exception is gone.  Now I'm getting a new one.  Dunno why, it says it's out of bounds but index+2 for the one I tested is the last element of the arraylist, and it even prints out the 3 elements. <br> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at version4.version4.findItem(version4.java:69)
 at version4.version4.main(version4.java:31)

Comment: Probably that's another question. but, i will answer it.you need to first ensure that index is not outside the bounds. if you list size is 3, then the valid index can be 0,1,2 and not 3

Comment: I retrieved the index of the sku entered, and then print out the next two elements after that by using index+1 and index+2, so it should only be adding 2 to the value of index which couldn't bring it to a higher number than the size of the arraylist :/

Comment: what's you index value?

Comment: I just did it a different way instead, was getting annoyed haha.  Thanks.